# how to make result of multiple choice in side of the answer

Tags: php, html

i want to make a multiple choice that if we choose wrong answer, then a text 'incorrect' will be displayed in side of the answer that we choose and if we choose right answer,  then a text 'correct' will be displayed in side of the answer that we choose. i using radio button. please help.

this is my index.php:

```
<?php

    include 'koneksi.php';
    session_start();
    $query = mysql_query("select * from t_soal") or die (mysql_error());
    //$_SESSION['soal'] = mysql_fetch_array($query);
    $_SESSION['soal'] = array();
    $_SESSION['no'] = 1;
    $_SESSION['score'] = 0;
    $_SESSION['option'] = array();
    $_SESSION['jawab'] = array();
    $i=0;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
        $_SESSION['soal'][] = $row;
        $_SESSION['option'][] = array($_SESSION['soal'][$i]['a'], $_SESSION['soal'][$i]['b'], $_SESSION['soal'][$i]['c'], $_SESSION['soal'][$i]['d']);
        $i++;
    }

    if(isset($_SESSION['soal'])){
        header("location:test.php");
    }
```

this is test.php:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $soal = $_SESSION['soal'];
    $no = $_SESSION['no'];
    if(isset($_POST['next'])){
        $_SESSION['jawab'][] = $_POST['option'];
        if($_POST['option'] == $soal[$no-2]['kunci']){
            $_SESSION['score'] = $_SESSION['score'] + 10;
        }
    }
    if(isset($soal[$no-1])){ 
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Latihan Soal</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="index.php">Kembali ke soal 1</a>
    <form action="" method="POST">
        <p>
        <?php
            echo $no.". "; $_SESSION['no']++; 
            echo $soal[$no-1]['soal']; 
            $jawaban = $_SESSION['option'][$no-1]; 
            shuffle($jawaban); 
        ?>
         </p>
        <?php
            for ($i=0; $i < 4; $i++) {
        ?>
            <input type="radio" name="option" value="<?php echo $jawaban[$i]; ?>" required/> <?php echo $jawaban[$i]; ?></br>
        <?php
            }
         ?>
        <input type="submit" name="next" value="next">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
<?php
    }else{
        header("location:result.php");
    }
?>
```

Comment: It does not look like you have made any effort to code what you want. You start the process and then ask for help if you get stuck. **SO is not a free coding service**

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all your script is working already, then:

In PHP:

You will need to assign a new parameter on this script:

```
if($_POST['option'] == $soal[$no-2]['kunci']){
    $_SESSION['score'] = $_SESSION['score'] + 10;
}
```

to

```
if($_POST['option'] == $soal[$no-2]['kunci']){
    $_SESSION['score'] = $_SESSION['score'] + 10;
    $_SESSION['correctAnswer'] = $soal[$no-2]['kunci']; // add sthing like this
}
```

and then, from

```
for ($i=0; $i < 4; $i++) {
    ?>
        <input type="radio" name="option" value="<?php echo $jawaban[$i]; ?>" required/> <?php echo $jawaban[$i]; ?></br>
    <?php
        }
```

to

```
for ($i=0; $i < 4; $i++) {
    ?>
    <input type="radio" name="option" value="<?php echo $jawaban[$i]; ?>" required/> <?php echo $jawaban[$i]; ?></br>
    <?php
    echo $jawaban[$i] == $_SESSION['correctAnswer'] ? " correct" : " incorrect";    
}
```

In JS: (much easier)

HTML files will looks like this:

```
<div class="correctAnswer">
    <input type="radio" name="theanswer" id="choice1" />
    <label for="choice1">Choice 1</label>
</div>
<div class="incorrectAnswer">
    <input type="radio" name="theanswer" id="choice2" />
    <label for="choice2">Choice 2</label>
</div>
```

and the JS will looks like this:

```
$(".correctAnswer").click(function() {
$(".checks").remove();
$(this).append("<span class='checks'> correct</span>");
});
$(".incorrectAnswer").click(function() {
    $(".checks").remove();
    $(this).append("<span class='checks'> incorrect</span>");
});
```

If you want a working example, please check this [fiddle link here](https://jsfiddle.net/ruxd/ptdxx865/).

Hope it helps !

Comment: theres will be an error Notice: Undefined index: correctAnswer in C:\xampp\htdocs\aa\test.php